# Cancelling a BackgroundWorker that performs a DB call

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a WPF application with a child window.Within that I'm doing a database connectivity check on a button click(in a background worker). The process take some time to complete and within that time if the user closes the child window by clicking on close button, the window closes but the background worker continues to run and displays the message after sometime.

Here is the sample code:

```
BackgroundWorker worker;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
                worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);

                bsyInd.IsBusy = true;
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
     void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (worker.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }

                    // checking database connectivity
                    string connstring=myconnstring;
                    SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(connstring);
                    con.Open();
                    if(con.State==ConnectionState.Open)
                       e.Result=true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                 e.Result=false;
                }

            }

            void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                bool canConnect=(bool)e.Result;
                if(canConnect)
                    MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed");

                bsyInd.IsBusy = false;
            }

    //close child window
    private void ChildWindow_CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //cancel the running process
        worker.CancelAsync();
    }
```

All the solutions I found online shows examples that continuosly  monitor/poll the CancellationPending property of the background worker within a loop inside Do_Work. Here as the process i intend to do doesn't require any loops, how can I monitor the CancellationPending status on child window close button click event and cancel the background process?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a way to abort the blocking `SqlConnection.Open` request?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that there is way to abort a blocking call to `SqlConnection.Open`, you could simply declare the `SqlConnection` object as a member variable in your class and execute the aborting call in the Close button handler.

```
private SqlConnection con;

private void ChildWindow_CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (con != null)
    {
        con.Dispose(); // or whatever would abort Open()
        con = null;
    }
}
```

In the worker thread `Open` would presumably throw kind of an Aborted exception, that you could catch and then set `e.Cancel = true;`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Actually I have a busy indicator that shows while the background worker checks for db connectivity. Do I have an option to keep that functionality same while also being able to cancel/abort the blocking call on window close.

Comment: You should be able to also update/remove the busy indicator in the catch block of the hypothetical exception.

Comment: Clemens - I tried that and the exception takes a while to happen. The call to dispose() doesn't abort the connection at once.

Comment: I don't see any other clean way. If it really takes too long, you would have to set up your own connection thread and abort it as Vincent has suggested. But you have to know what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Dennis, you could use an approach with AutoResetEvent, see [AutoResetEvent Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx)

You signal to the thread on which the sql connection is happening that the resource can be released.

You are still using a separate thread so nothing should be blocked, but with the ability now to communicate between the threads and specially notify one of them to release the resources. Apologies if this is not in the format intended.

That link has an example of how to use the AutoResetEvent.